# Button hover effect down-top color change

Tags: css

how can I reverse this button hover effect from currently top-down to down-top?

```css
.btn-1 {
  position: relative;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #4285f4;
  color: #4285f4;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.slide-btn, .slide-btn::after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slide-btn::before, .slide-btn::after {
  background: #4285f4;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-1::after {
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-1:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <button class="btn-1 slide-btn">Button 1</button>
```

Played around for quite some time, e.g. changing to .btn-1::after { height: 100%; } and .btn-1::after { height:0; } ... which gives me the down-top effect but with reversed colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change top to bottom in .btn-1::after
https://jsfiddle.net/rp042h6j/

```
.btn-1::after {
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.btn-1::after` change `top` to `bottom`:

```css
.btn-1 {
  position: relative;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #4285f4;
  color: #4285f4;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.slide-btn,
.slide-btn::after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.slide-btn::before,
.slide-btn::after {
  background: #4285f4;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn-1::after {
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-1:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-1 slide-btn">Button 1</button>
```